# Azure cosmosdb emulator issue

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I installed the azure cosmosdb emulator and when I try to open  `https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html` I get the following error in Microsoft edge,

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED*
```

I deleted the data in the **`AppData\Local\CosmosDBEmulator`** folder and I tried to start from the command line as follows:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /port=8084 /EnableEndPointDiscovery=false
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /NoFirewall
```

But still no luck

Any ideas?

Comment: After uninstalling, can you try deleting the remaining folder/files of "C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator" ?

Comment: I tried uninstalling/deleting/reinstalling but made no difference, still getting the same error

Comment: also can you check if there is a process already running? if so kill and do the same again

Comment: also try netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: where are you running the command?

Comment: Maybe take this to [chat]? Comments aren't really the place for an extended discussion.

Comment: I am running from the cmd line as administrator

Comment: I've resolved the issue by running in the command prompt lodctr /R to rebuild performance counter. I had to run it twice. I closed and restarted the emulator and is all working now!

Comment: @GarryA Please post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue by running in the command prompt lodctr /R to rebuild performance counter. I had to run it twice. I closed and restarted the emulator and is all working now